# Where do we go to ask subjective questions about programming?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

[I wrote a pretty long post about how to design an economics system and submitted it to stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874010/how-would-you-build-an-economics-system-into-a-game-like-civilization-5) thinking that I could get various opinions on how this would be done.  Instead the mods flagged it and killed it within a few minutes.

Since subjective topics are not allowed on Stack Overflow, where can we go to discuss such a thing?

Comment: programmers.se Looks to be full of subjective questions.  I'll post there.

Comment: @ArronS Your question does not look appropriate for programmers, for the same reason it's not appropriate on SO; it's just too broad.  People can and have written entire books on this subject.  There's no way to fit something comprehensive on that topic into an SO answer.

Comment: @ArronS you better think twice: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773

Comment: I post such a question of this SO because this is where all the developers are.  If I post in any other forum, I'll get a bunch of arm chair bikeshedding instead of practical thoughts from people who actually write code.

Comment: @ArronS You'll get the exact same thing even on SO, which is why SO doesn't want questions like that.  SO has quality questions because it gets rid of questions that aren't of high quality.